# Internet Explorer 9 doesn't support css3 style

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, media

I have below script, it's doing fine in firefox and chrome. ie9 doesn't show the change of colors.

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #FF77BB;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
body {
background-color: #8A2BE2;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
body {
background-color: #FF8C00;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
body {
background-color: #7FFF00;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
body {
background-color: #CC0011;
}
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: i think you have an extra closing bracket in last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me, just get rid of the extra } at the very end, the other browsers may not make it an issue but IE9 is very picky, if one thing is off it breaks the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, i did that but still not working. Do i need to change any settings..!! addin's...!!

Comment: check and make sure you don't have compatibility view on, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-to-use-Compatibility-View-in-Internet-Explorer-9

Comment: Yeah, IE is picky. i missed <!DOCTYPE html />, now it's fine